# How To Edit 'Main Content' Block in CS Cart`

Tags: html, cs-cart

First time asking a question on here.  Before we start - I'm not a web dev, web designer or any other kind of web pro.  Everything I know I've taught myself and I'm kinda just learning everything as I go along.  So please, if we can, make it easy as poss for me!  That in mind - lets continue. :D

I want to edit the Main Content block on my CS Cart website on the Product Pages.

I want to move the ADD TO CART button further to the left so I can add an info banner box at the side of the Product Price etc.  See below;

[image: http://s7.postimg.org/k8lhazr0n/is_like_this.jpg]

[image: http://s4.postimg.org/ekovcyix5/want_it_like_this.jpg]

Look forward to hearing your suggestions!

Comment: Really struggling wih this, would love some assistance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own product data template:
Place your file into the `design/themes/your_theme_name/templates/addons/my_changes/blocks/product_templates/custom_layout.tpl`
Copy the contents of`design/themes/your_theme_name/templates/blocks/product_templates/default_template.tpl` file, and modify the main layout on your own. (My example needs the My changes add-on, so please check if it is enabled in the Add-on manager)

Comment: Thanks ISTI, I'll check this way out as well.

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at [this](http://forum.cs-cart.com/topic/29828-a-simple-way-to-add-any-content-on-any-place-on-template/).

I was struggling with this problem too and this is a great solution! If you have any other questions feel free to ask.